# How to extract 24 different frames per second from video?

Tags: android, frame, gif, mp4, mediametadataretriever

I want to create a **GIF from mp4** video. So I need to extract the frames from video first. Here is the code I use to extract frames:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(mFilePath);
Bitmap bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(i,
                    MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

Note that variable `i` is time in **microseconds**. Since I want to get 24 frames/second, I call `retriever.getFrameAtTime()` with `i` = 42000, 84000, .... (microseconds).

The problem is: when I collect extracted frames to a video, I see only 4-5 different frames. In other words, I didn't get a smooth video. It seems that `MediaMetadataRetriever` often returns the same frame with different given time. Please help me!

Comment: Shouldn't `i` be a multiple of 41666 instead 42000.  Or more specific, `i = (frameindex * 1000000)/24;`

Comment: Which version of Android are you developing for? 6.0 has a bug where OPTION_CLOSEST only returns key frames.

Comment: I am facing the same problem now, is your problem solved?